# Conditional displaying values in R

Tags: r

I'd like to see which values have a particular entry issue, but I'm not getting things done right.
For instance, I need to print on screen values from column "c" but conditional of a given value from "b" say where [b==0]. 
Finally, I need to add a new string for those whose condition is true.

```
 df<- structure(list(a = c(11.77, 10.9, 10.32, 10.96, 9.906, 10.7, 
 11.43, 11.41, 10.48512, 11.19), b = c(2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 
 4, 0), c = c("q", "c", "v", "f", "", "e", "e", "v", "a", "c")), .Names = c("a", 
 "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried this without success:

```
if(df[b]==0){
print(df$c)
}


if((df[b]==0)&(df[c]=="v")){
df[c] <-paste("2")
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```
rows <- which(df$b==0)
if (length(rows)>0) {
  print(df$c[rows])
  df$c[rows] <- paste(df$c[rows],'2')
  ## maybe you wanted to have:
  # df$c[rows] <- '2'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The correct syntax is like `df[rows, columns]`, so you could try:

```
df[df$b==0, "c"]
```

You can accomplish changing values using `ifelse`:

```
df$c <- ifelse(df$b==0 & df$c=="v", paste(df$c, 2, sep=""), df$c)
```

Comment: Except that it won't work as expected if there are *NA* values: the truth value of *NA==0* is *NA*, so the **ifelse** construct is not suited to this context. Or I am mistaken somewhere?

Comment: I guess it depends how NA values should be handled in the particular problem.

Comment: You are right :) I just wanted to share a hard-learned lesson with a code that I had to work with, written by somebody else, and which contained this precise bug. I believe it is in general a good practice to use **which** when subsetting, or to explicitly write the condition (df$b==0 & !is.na(df$b)).

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to subset data in R, like e.g.:

```
df$c[df$b == 0]
df[df$b == 0, "c"]
subset(df, b == 0, c)
with(df, c[b == 0])
# ...
```

To conditionally add another column (here: TRUE/FALSE):

```
df$e <- FALSE; df$e[df$b == 0] <- TRUE
df <- transform(df, c = ifelse(b == 0, TRUE, FALSE))
df <- within(df, e <- ifelse(b == 0, TRUE, FALSE))
# ...
```

Comment: ... and all these ways to subset data have one point in common: they will drive you mad if you happen to have *NA* values in **df$b**. To give you an example, if **df$b** is **c(0,1,NA)** and **df$c** is **c(5,6,7)**, then **df$c[df$b == 0]** will yield **c(5,NA)**.

In my experience, it is a good practice to subset with the **which** function: e.g. **df$c[which(df$b == 0)]**

Comment: @Jealie Well `NA`s are there for a reason as is the way R handles them by default. I'd say both ways, logical indexing and indexing by rows (`which`), have their right to exist.